# Which data do I have to store in DB once I get Token data in Linkedin API?

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

I assume workflow for OAuth is very similar in various sites. (twitter, linkedin)
I can successfully get requestToken, accessToken. 
Is it okay, if I just store Accesstoken and use it later???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the generally accepted practice.  I use this workflow on a few sites and based on the posts on the LinkedIn Developer's site, it looks like the method that most people are using.

The only trick is to cover yourself in the case that the user rejects your application's access rights; filter all responses from the LinkedIn API looking for an error indicating that the access token is no longer valid (you should be doing this filtering anyways for throttling issues).

Comment: What about oauth_token_secret? Needs to be stored as well?

Comment: @bart - yes, store both tokens.

Comment: I didn't think so, however that's what I'm having to do here otherwise it won't work...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509493/linkedin-oauthlinkedin